# Assign to object in for loop with iterator as part of the object name

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `COG` representing an experiment with a couple of different conditions. For a couple of calculations, I'd like to subset this dataframe into as many subsets as there are conditionsm, and I'd like the subset name to be something like `COG.i` with `i` being the condition.

```
for (i in unique(COG$cond)) {
 ??? <- subset(COG, COG$cond == i)
}
```

What would I need to put in place of the `???` ? It's not `COG.i` and definetely not `paste0("COG.", i)`

(I realize that one could also take care to "tidy" the data or use Dummy Codes for the different conditions, but apart from the statistics I'd like to get a better grasp of R in the first place.)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try `split(COG, COG$cond)` to get a list consisting of multiple data frames forming a partition of your original data frame.

Comment: Perhaps see `?assign`? Something like `assign(paste0("COG.", i), subset(...))`.

Comment: Thanks, @alexis_laz, that works. May not be as elegant as Blue Magister's solution, but that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Lists exist for this very purpose. Instead of having multiple variables, put the results in a list.

As suggested in the comments, you should use `split` to split your dataset into different subsets.

```
COG.split <- split(COG, COG$cond)
```

You can then access the different subsets using the `[[ ]]` operator, or use the `*apply` family of functions to perform operations on the various subsets.